# How to fix background image always on the same position

Tags: html, css, image, background, background-image

Do you know how i can fix my background image always on the same position?

My website is [www.ivr.immo](http://ivr.immo) and i got a big background image. I want that the background image is so fixed that the house roof is always under the left menu. I mean even if the window is resized, the house roof should be always under the menu. I tried it but I can't do this, there are a lot of options you have for background. I think that the image should be bigger than screen and then you can position the image without having a repeat of the image. I hope someone can help me with the css code.
The background image is in the body tag of the website.

My CSS Code (its not much):

```
body {
    background: url("../assets/bg5.jpg") center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
 }
```

polest

Comment: you can write media query and set background-position-x = x% for each screen size or use JavaScript to set background position.

Comment: Can you post the code that you have right now?

Comment: @adamk22 i posted the code in my question

Answer (score 1):

You mixing two things together: magnification (picture) and centering (html elements).

I have two solutions in mind:

1. Set your menu on a position with a percentage from left, for
   example: *left: 12%;*. but be aware that this will change your layout.
2. Use:

   ```
   background: url("../assets/bg5.jpg") center;
   /*background-size: cover; */  /* delete this line in your code */
   ```

   and use a own picture with different clipping and width for different screen-sizes.